# Logging from within a C++ Windows DLL file

Tags: c++, logging, dll

What is the best practice of logging DLL activity and internal parameter values.
I wrote a DLL that is used by a few applications I wrote. Lately, some users were complaining about problems that I suspect are related to this DLL but I cannot reproduce on my dev machine.
I'd like send them an equivalent DLL file that will log its activity, such as function calls, function return values and some internal parameters.
I don't think there should be a problem for a DLL to create a log file and write to it. Is there a common practice related to this issue. Is there a standard place to write the data to?

Answer (score 3):

I am currently facing a similar issue of how to provide logging from a DLL.  The way I went about it is to provide callback function setters and a callback type header file as part of the API. That way, the caller of the dll can create their own type of logging (boost, log4cpp, etc) and the dll will call the callback function in the exe that the user can do whatever they want with the data.  In my case, I forward the log msgs to a boost logger that is instantiated in the exe.  It's a little hacky looking but seems to work pretty well since the exe controls when and how to log everything and the user can format the data any way they choose.

Answer (score 2):

You could provide an interface on your DLL which allows the user to provide a log file path/handle as the logging sink.

If you auto-generate the log file you'll probably want the file name to contain the process name and the process id (to disambiguate multiple simultaneous runs).

on unix machines the usual place is /var/log

on windows the standard way is to log to the event log (a separate subsystem of the OS).
I would suggest using the active user's TEMP directory if you want to log to file...

...or you could be clever and get the DLL to log to your own machines via TCP.

Comment: Interesting options. I wouldn't like the user to do anything and of course I wouldn't dare opening a TCP link. So this leaves me with opening a file on %TEMP%. Doesn't the application has to be elevated for that? I'll check it.